# Generating weighted duplicate lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, duplicates

I have a few lists as follows:

```
l1=['InitialRequest','Approved','WorkStarted','OnHold','InProgress','OnHold','InProgress','Completed']

l2=['InitialRequest','Approved','WorkStarted','OnHold','OnHold','OnHold','OnHold','Cancelled']

l3=['InitialRequest','Approved','WorkStarted','InProgress','InProgress','InProgress','InProgress','Completed']
```

...upto l7. I need to maintain the sequence as given in the lists, and generate each of the lists 15000 times. So I created a list of these lists:

```
Status=[l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7]
```

And I have tried this:

```
Status_b = list(np.random.choice(Status, 15000, replace=True, p=[0.1,0.02,0.5,0.08,0.03,0.07,0.1,0.1]))
```

But I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>  File "<ipython-input-168-d6488b73dd38>", line 1, in <module>
>    Status_b = list(np.random.choice(Status, 15000, replace=True, p=[0.1,0.02,0.5,0.08,0.03,0.07,0.1,0.1]))
>
>  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1117, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
>
> ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
> ```

Can somebody give me a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of letting `random` choose from the lists themselves, let it choose the indices:

```
weights = [0.1,0.02,0.5,0.08,0.03,0.07,0.1,0.1]
status_idx = np.random.choice(len(status), 15000, replace=True, p=weights)
status_b  = [Status[i] for i in status_idx)
```